# Tax Bracket dealing with if and else if

Tags: java

I am having a problem trying to get the correct values to come out on this program. The purspose of the program is to calculate gross income tax I think it may be a rounding error, but I am not sure. I have run multiple test cases, and the larger the number, the larger the error.

Test Cases: 
1.  single
  a.    Tax on: 10,240
b.  Correct Output 1118.5 
Actual output 1118

2.
Filling Jointly
tax on 70,000
Correct Output 9875
Actual output 9665

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Tax
{

public static void main(String args[])
{
    Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
    int repeats=0;
    System.out.println("How many people are you filing for?");
    repeats=scan.nextInt();
    for(int i=0;i<repeats;i++)
        calculate();
}
public static void calculate()
{
    Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean isGood=false;
    int bracket=0;
    while(isGood==false)
    {
    System.out.println("Please choose your Filing Status:\n1: Single\n2: Married Filed Jointly\n3: Married Filling Separately\n4: Head of Household");
    bracket=scan.nextInt();
    if(bracket>0&&bracket<5)
        isGood=true;
    }
    System.out.println("Please enter your income (Round to the nearest dollar)");
    double income=scan.nextDouble();
    double [] sBracket={8350,33950,82250,171550,372950};
    double [] fjBracket={16700,67900,137050,208850,372950};
    double [] fsBracket ={8350,33950,68525,104425,186475};
    double [] hhBracket={11950,45500,117450,190200,372950};
    double [] myBracket;
    double [] percents={.1,.15,.25,.28,.33,.35};
    myBracket=sBracket;
    if(bracket==2)
        myBracket=fjBracket;
    if(bracket==3)
        myBracket=fsBracket;
    if(bracket==4)
        myBracket=hhBracket;
    int sum=0;





    if(income<myBracket[0])
        {
        sum+=income*percents[0];
        }       
    else
        {
            sum+=(myBracket[0]*percents[0]);
            income-=myBracket[0];


            if(income>myBracket[1])
                {
                    sum+=(myBracket[1]*percents[1]);
                    income-=myBracket[1];
                    System.out.println("If Ran");
                }
            else if(income<myBracket[1]&&income>0)
                {
                    System.out.println("Else IF ran");
                    sum+=(income*percents[1]);
                    income-=myBracket[1];
                }

            if(income>myBracket[2])
                {
                    sum+=(myBracket[2]*percents[2]);
                    income-=myBracket[2];
                }
            else if(income<myBracket[2]&&income>0)
                {
                    sum+=(income*percents[2]);
                    income-=myBracket[2];
                }

            if(income>myBracket[3])
                {
                    sum+=(myBracket[3]*percents[3]);
                    income-=myBracket[3];
                }
            else if(income<myBracket[3]&&income>0)
                {
                    sum+=(income*percents[3]);
                    income-=myBracket[3];
                }
            if(income>myBracket[4])
                {
                    sum+=(income*percents[5]);
                    income-=myBracket[4];
                }

        }
    System.out.println("Your Tax is :"+sum);    
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have used sum as int. please use sum as double and see the magic. It is rounding the values in sum so you are getting wrong value in result.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Tax
{

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
        int repeats=0;
        System.out.println("How many people are you filing for?");
        repeats=scan.nextInt();
        for(int i=0;i<repeats;i++)
            calculate();
    }
    public static void calculate()
    {
        Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean isGood=false;
        int bracket=0;
        while(isGood==false)
        {
        System.out.println("Please choose your Filing Status:\n1: Single\n2: Married Filed Jointly\n3: Married Filling Separately\n4: Head of Household");
        bracket=scan.nextInt();
        if(bracket>0&&bracket<5)
            isGood=true;
        }
        System.out.println("Please enter your income (Round to the nearest dollar)");
        double income=scan.nextDouble();
        double [] sBracket={8350,33950,82250,171550,372950};
        double [] fjBracket={16700,67900,137050,208850,372950};
        double [] fsBracket ={8350,33950,68525,104425,186475};
        double [] hhBracket={11950,45500,117450,190200,372950};
        double [] myBracket;
        double [] percents={.1,.15,.25,.28,.33,.35};
        myBracket=sBracket;
        if(bracket==2)
            myBracket=fjBracket;
        if(bracket==3)
            myBracket=fsBracket;
        if(bracket==4)
            myBracket=hhBracket;
        double sum=0;





        if(income<myBracket[0])
            {
            sum+=income*percents[0];
            }       
        else
            {
                sum+=(myBracket[0]*percents[0]);
                income-=myBracket[0];


                if(income>myBracket[1])
                    {
                        sum+=(myBracket[1]*percents[1]);
                        income-=myBracket[1];
                        System.out.println("If Ran");
                    }
                else if(income<myBracket[1]&&income>0)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Else IF ran");
                        sum+=(income*percents[1]);
                        income-=myBracket[1];
                    }

                if(income>myBracket[2])
                    {
                        sum+=(myBracket[2]*percents[2]);
                        income-=myBracket[2];
                    }
                else if(income<myBracket[2]&&income>0)
                    {
                        sum+=(income*percents[2]);
                        income-=myBracket[2];
                    }

                if(income>myBracket[3])
                    {
                        sum+=(myBracket[3]*percents[3]);
                        income-=myBracket[3];
                    }
                else if(income<myBracket[3]&&income>0)
                    {
                        sum+=(income*percents[3]);
                        income-=myBracket[3];
                    }
                if(income>myBracket[4])
                    {
                        sum+=(income*percents[5]);
                        income-=myBracket[4];
                    }

            }
        System.out.println("Your Tax is :"+sum);    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about changing your sum variable from an `int` to a `double`.

The reason why I say that is because you will get the decimal precision in the final sum, especially where you say:

Correct Output 1118.5 Actual output 1118

the actual output would then be 1118.5

```
double sum = 0.0; // rest of code
System.out.println("Your tax is: " + sum);
```